# MongoDB - Select rows by their sequence number in one query

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an object in the db which contains an array of strings.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("abc123..."),
    "Lines": [
        "string 1",
        "string 2",
        "string 3",
        "...",
        "string 100"
    ]
}
```

I need to select rows by their sequence number in one query.

For example, I need lines 1, 7, and 15.

```cs
var projection = Builders<ContentEntity>.Projection
    .Slice(e => e.Lines2, 1, 1)
    .Slice(e => e.Lines2, 7, 1)
    .Slice(e => e.Lines2, 15, 1);

var entity = await GetContext(categoryId).ContentEntities
    .Find(e => e.Id == contentId)
    .Project<ContentEntity>(projection)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

return entity;
```

If I use the slice operator like this, I only get row #15.

I need to select rows by their sequence number in one query from MongoDB with С#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think that the last `.Slice()` overwrite the previous `.Slice()`.

Pass the query as `BsonDocument` instead of using the MongoDB Driver Fluent API which is difficult to implement for your scenario.

> Query

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  Lines2: {
    $filter: {
      input: "$Lines",
      cond: {
        $in: [
          {
            $indexOfArray: [
              "$Lines",
              "$$this"
            ]
          },
          [
            0,
            6,
            14
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V8QVbvieazB)

> MongoDB .NET Driver syntax

```cs
var projection = new BsonDocument
{
    {
        "Lines", new BsonDocument
        {
            {
                "$filter", new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "input", "$Lines" },
                    {
                        "cond", new BsonDocument
                        {
                            {
                                "$in", new BsonArray
                                {
                                    new BsonDocument("$indexOfArray", new BsonArray
                                    {
                                        "$Lines",
                                        "$$this"
                                    }),
                                    new BsonArray { 0, 6, 14 }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```